# Caldeirada - the Portuguese fish soup

Tags: fish, soup, portuguese-cuisine

Caldeirada is a fish soup/stew very popular in Portugal, which has several recipes (mainly suggesting different kind of fish). It is cooked in a large(r) pot and these recipes have all in common to start covering the pot with a layer of sliced onion rings. Then you add layers of other vegetables and the last layers would be the fish. You are not supposed to stir while cooking.

Why is the first layer always onions? Is this just a question of adding sufficient onion flavor to the dish or is there another reason?

[image]

some recipe's excerpts and respective links (all in Portuguese)

- https://pt.petitchef.com/receitas/prato-principal/caldeirada-fid-1512802
  *- In a reinforced deep pan arrange the ingredients in alternate layers, starting with a layer of onions followed by garlic, tomatoes, peppers, potatoes and fish*
- https://www.pingodoce.pt/receitas/caldeirada-de-peixe/ *- Step 3:
  Pour half the olive oil into a large pan and layer the vegetables on top, starting with the onion.*
- https://www.vaqueiro.pt/recipes/caldeirada-a-moda-de-peniche-198125 *-Peel the onion, cut them into thin slices and spread them over the bottom of the pan. Peel the potatoes, cut them into rounds and place them on top of the onions. Wash and cut the peppers into strips taking care to remove all the seeds and white skin. Spread the pepper strips over the potatoes. Wash the tomatoes, cut them into pieces and arrange them on top of the remaining vegetables.*

Comment: I just checked three different online Caldeirada recipes, as well as one in a Portuguese cookbook, and NONE of them start with a thick layer of onion rings.  So you're looking at one specific recipe ... not recipes for the dish in general.  Please link or quote the recipe you're following, thanks!

Comment: @FuzzyChef I can do so, but they are all in Portuguese, shall I post the links and then translate the essential? And it is not a thick layer of onion rings, it is a layer of thick cut onion rings

Comment: Nah, just link in Portuguese.  Folks can use Google Translate if they want.

Comment: Interesting!  None of the English-language recipes I can find use the kind of "passive layering" in those Portuguese recipes.

Answer (score 6):

Tradition counts for a lot in many cuisines, so the answer may be 'because that's the way it's always been' in Portuguese cuisine. However, I would put the onion at the bottom because it takes the longest to cook. By putting the onions at the bottom they will get the earliest and therefore longest exposure to heat. Although you don't include the recipe, I would suspect that the layering starts with the longest to cook ingredients at the bottom and the shortest at the top, with the fish requiring the least cooking.

Comment: Since many caldeirada recipes start with chopped or diced onions, often mixed with garlic and/or peppers, this is def. the answer.  It's just the standard technique of adding the strong aeromatics first.